# (SyntaxError): missing ] after element list when using eval

Tags: javascript, eval

I get following error  `(SyntaxError): missing ] after element list` when using `eval` function.
Returned JSON is pretty simple, so I don't undestand where is error.

```
[{"title":"sfsdf","id":1}{"title":"m356","id":12}]
```

Comment: There is no comma between the Objects in this Array.

Comment: @g.d.d.c Might as well post that as the answer and collect some free rep.

Comment: (There are generally better ways to handle JSON/data-interchange than `eval`; I hope it's just a testing artifact exposed here.)

Comment: @antisanity - I usually try to comment first, in case the OP wants to remove the question.  Posted though, in case they leave it up.

Comment: @jbabey what I can use instead? Why not eval? because is not safe?

Comment: @MyTitle if you have a javascript object as a string (JSON), you should use `JSON.parse(yourString);` instead of `eval(yourString)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As an answer for completeness.  Your JSON is invalid.  You need a comma between the Objects like so:

```
[{"title":"sfsdf","id":1},{"title":"m356","id":12}]
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have lost  the comma between the Object,the Second Jquery will parse the Object automaticly. i suggest you don't use this method. i also meet thie question,but there're some difference from yours.